# Hahn Banach extension theorem for locally convex spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, locally-convex-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I think the Hahn-Banach extension theorem states:

> If $X$ is a Hausdorff lcs, $M\subseteq X$ a subspace and $f:M\to\Bbb K$ is a continuous linear map, then there is a continuous linear map $F:X\to\Bbb K$ with $F\lvert_M=f$.

However I cannot find a reference for this version. Usually the Hahn-Banach extension theorem is states that a functional dominated by *one* sub-linear function can have its domain extended so that the domination remains intact.

In the case of a locally convex space one usually has an infinite amount of semi-norms generating the topology. Suppose one has $C_p\in\Bbb R$ so that $|f(x)|≤ C_p p(x)$ for all semi-norms $p$ and $x\in M$, can one choose an extension so that this system of inequalities remains true for all $x\in X$?

Comment: Reference for the form of the extension theorem you state: Theorem 3.6 in Rudin's _Functional Analysis_ (Second Edition).

Comment: But the second version is not in general true? (ie the extension preserves sub-norms)

Comment: Well, if there is a $C_p$ for _every_ continuous seminorm $p$ on $X$, then $f = 0$, since for every $x \in X$ there is a continuous seminorm vanishing at $x$. Thus there trivially is an extension satisfying the same inequalities on all of $X$. I think you meant to consider only the family of continuous seminorms on $X$ for which such an inequality holds on $M$. I'm not yet sure whether it's always possible to extend $f$ preserving the inequalities.

Comment: It's not always possible. Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, $M = \mathbb{R}\cdot (1,1)$, and $f((t,t)) = t$. Consider the seminorms $p \colon (x,y) \mapsto \lvert x\rvert$, $q \colon (x,y) \mapsto \lvert y\rvert$. We have $\lvert f(\xi)\rvert \leqslant p(\xi), q(\xi)$ on $M$, but a linear functional $\lambda$ on $X$ with $\lvert\lambda(\xi)\rvert \leqslant p(\xi), q(\xi)$ for all $\xi \in X$ must be the zero functional.

Comment: Oh wow, so thats why I never saw such a "simultaneous" domination statement, such a statement doesn't make sense!

Comment: @s.harp Another reference is Murphy's book "C*-algebras and operator theory" p271, A11 (this is the appendix).